# PHP echo with database $rows and an a href link inside of an <li>

Tags: php, html, html-lists, href

I need help in the proper syntax to enable an a href inside of a PHP echo that list out database $row fields?

Here is my php:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$u = $row["username"];

echo "<li>". $row['avatar']. '&nbsp'. $row['firstname']. '&nbsp' .$row['lastname'] ."</li>";
}


Here is my a href code: 
<a href="user.php?u=$u.>

?>
```

The question is: How do I get the ahref inside the echo

with proper sequence? I believe it has to do with escaping the '.", but for the life of me, I can't get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What href are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Simple example:

```
$link = '/link/to/page';
echo '<li><a href="' . $link . '">' . $row['avatar'] . '&nbsp;'. $row['firstname']. '&nbsp;' .$row['lastname'] ."</a></li>";
```

Also note that html-entities (e. g. `&nbsp;`) have `;` in the end.

Comment: Thank you all for your help...it worked!

If I have another question about php syntax, but on a different issue, do I jut ask on this post, or do I post a NEW question?

Comment: New question is always a preferrable option.

Answer (score 0):

Change the echo line:

```
echo "<li><a href=\"user.php?u=$u\">". $row['avatar']. '&nbsp'. $row['firstname']. '&nbsp' .$row['lastname'] ."</a></li>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
echo '<li><a href="user.php?u='.$u.'">'.$row['avatar'].'&nbsp;'.$row['firstname'].'&nbsp;'.$row['lastname'].'</a></li>';
```

Comment: Close `a` tag, please)

Comment: You're missing the closing `</a>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple you should try this, I just made a little change in your code, hope it will work for you

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $u = $row["username"];
    echo "<li><a href='user.php?u=".$u."'>". $row['avatar']. '&nbsp'. $row['firstname']. '&nbsp' .$row['lastname'] ."</a></li>";
}
?>
```